# Verify Proof: $P(P(x))=[P(x)]^{k}$

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification

I solved a problem and got the right answer, however, the book I was using used a totally different method. I'm wondering whether my proof is correct and I didn't do some silly error (which happens a lot).

Question:
Let $k$ be a positive integer. Prove that if $P(x)$ is a polynomial and has the property:

$$P(P(x))=[P(x)]^{k}$$
$P(x)$ must be in the form:
$$P(x)=x^k$$

**My proof**: Let $P(s)=0$
$$P(P(s))=P(0)=[P(s)]^k=0$$
Now let $P(c)=s$
$$P(P(c))=P(s)=0=[P(c)]^k=s^k=0$$

Thus all roots $s$ are equal to zero, and the polynomial takes the form:
$$(x-0)(x-0)(x-0)(x-0)...=x^n$$
Doing some analysis on the degree of $P(P(x))=[P(x)]^{k}$ reveals that $n=k$ and the proof is done.

The proof in the book, however, is so much more complex. Did I miss something or make a logical error? If you want to see the proof from the book, just ask.

Comment: When introducing $c$ such that $P(c) = s$ you assumed the root $s$ is in the image of the polynomial, which is not true in general. Take $(x+1)^2$ : the (double) root is $-1$ and yet the polynomial is non-negative on all $\mathbb R$. You may however be able to find such a $c$ in the complex numbers but I am not certain.

Comment: Well according to the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra there must be some root (I think). Whether its complex or not depends on the circumstance. If I'm not mistaken (again, I get things wrong all the time), $P(x)-s=0$ should have some root.

Comment: Oh yes so it definitely works when considering complex roots, then your proof seems fine to me! You should perhaps just note that $P$ should be non constant, otherwise $P = 1$ would also work if I am not mistaking.

Comment: As long as it has a nonzero degree.